# Add timeout to service jboss

Tags: jboss

I want to add timeout to service in JBoss.

The problem is that when I run this row for WSDL:

```
Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, serviceName);
```

I get timeout from WSDL like this:

> org.jboss.ws.core.WSTimeoutException: Timeout after: 30000ms

I try to add timeout to my service like:

```
((BindingProvider)service).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout", 500);
//            ((BindingProvider)service).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout", 500);
```

but I have exception.
What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout` and `javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout`.

Eg:

```
//Set timeout until a connection is established
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", "6000");

//Set timeout until the response is received
((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout", "1000");
```

Ref: [Develop a JAX-WS Client Application](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Develop_a_JAX-WS_Client_Application.html)